# Microsoft Print to PDF driver missing in Microsoft Server

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-generation, driver, windows-server-2012

I developed a C#, web forms **application that generates a PDF document server-side and sends it to the client**. I generate the PDF using *Microsoft Print To PDF* **(MPTP)**, *PrintDocument*, and *PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics.DrawString*. This works great on my local machine.

Enter server: When I uploaded my application and tried running it on my server, I get an error saying there's no printer installed. I check in Printers and devices and behold, MPTP isn't listed on the server (one fix for my problem is setting MPTP to default printer).

If you don't have the MPTP in "Printers and devices":

- Open "Turn Windows features on or off" and just check MPTP.

The problem is I don't have MPTP there either. To fix that:

- Open Devices and Printers
- Add Printer
- "The printer that I want isn’t listed"
- "Add a local printer or network printer with manual settings"
- Select port "FILE: (Print to File)" (i tried other ports and it's the same)
- In the left (Manufacturer) part choose Microsoft, in the right part chose MPTP

It should install the drivers for MPTP, but the **problem is I don't have MPTP on the list**! This is the part that is problematic.

I can't find help for this problem online (couldn't find even unanswered questions). I couldn't find drivers online so I could install them manually and have no idea how to fix it.

I tried generating a PDF using CutePDF Writer and Spire.PDF (I did generate the PDF, but local characters aren't working [č,š,ž] and I have to use PdfDocument, PdfSection, PdfTextWidget). I don't like generating with Spire.PDF because I must implement the correct header and signature for multipaged documents (which is a pain in the ass and I would prefer using the already written and tested code that uses PrintDocument and MPTP).

**Why is the Microsoft Print to PDF driver missing from my server?**

***Server info***: Microsoft Windows Server Version 6.2 (Build 9200). 
Internet Information Services Version 8.5.9600.16384.

Comment: What server version?

Comment: I edited the info into the post @Alex

Comment: 6.2 is Server 2012 but you state Windows 10 (which isn't a server) which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@AlexK was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500091/microsoft-print-to-pdf-driver-missing#comment64401308_38500091). I am new to working with servers and mistakenly thought it ran Windows 10 when it actually used Server 2012 R2.

The problem is I was googling "Windows 10 print to pdf". When I tried searching Server 2012 I found out that ***Print to PDF* doesn't exist on Server 2012**, which is why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a solution, but do I have a workaround for printing a document on Windows Server 2012 R2 if you have a Windows 10 PC you can use.  Here are the steps:

1. On the Windows Server 2012 R2 Machine, go to the Start Menu.
2. Find "Turn Windows Features On or Off" (Probably requires Admin privileges)
3. The Server Manager will launch
4. Installation Type > Role-based or feature-based installation
5. Select local server
6. Server Roles > Turn on Print and Document Services > Print Server
7. Features > XPS Viewer
8. Install

This will allow you to print to Microsoft XPS Document Writer which will create a ".oxps" file that you can save to the server.  Copy that file to your Windows 10 computer and you can then:

1. Open the .oxps file on the Windows 10 PC using the XPS viewer that is installed by default.
2. Print > Select Printer > Microsoft Print to PDF
3. Print

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to first print to XPS using the Windows XPS printer, then post process convert the XPS file to PDF using GhostScript's GhostXPS utility.

In my C# applications, I use the System.Diagnostics.Process to setup the parameters and launch the gxpswin64.exe command line executable.

Here is an example:
[Convert XPS to PDF without Printer Driver](http://minhtech.com/windows/convert-xps-to-pdf-without-printer-driver/)

References:

[GhostScript.com](https://ghostscript.com)

[GhostXPS.html](https://ghostscript.com/GhostXPS.html)